# How to add a custom EventHandler to the PaintEventHandler?

Tags: c#, event-handling, paint

As a C# exercise, I want to add a custom PaintEventHandler that draws a rectangle to my form whenever it is drawn. I have the following:

1) A delegate

```
public delegate void MyPaintFormEventHandler(object sender, PaintEventArgs e);
```

2) A method to be executed, drawing the rectangle.

```
private void draw_red_rectangle(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{ /* Implementation here */ }
```

3) A subscription to the Paint event of the Form.

```
this.Paint += new MyPaintFormEventHandler(draw_red_rectangle);
```

However, this piece of code together does not compile, for the following reason:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'use_graphics.MyPaintFormEventHandler' to 'System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler'

Can anyone help me out by pinpointing what I am doing wrong and how I could fix this?

Comment: You don't need to create your own delegate Instead use `System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that you have declared your own delegate type. You can simply use :

```
this.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(draw_red_rectangle);
```

or

```
this.Paint += draw_red_rectangle;
```

Comment: It can be so easy, once you know it! This works as a charm, thanks!